# Why Epoch wise Accuracy/loss is changing always from high to low?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, loss

[Please check the attached photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eeLS.png)

Here the model serves the disease classification from ECG data.Model is given below. But the accuracy for validation and train data are changing from high to low in every epoch. How can i overcome the problem

```
input_img = Input(shape=(feature, depth), name='ImageInput')
x = autoencoder_model(input_img)
x = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv1_1')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv1_2')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, name='pool1')(x)

x = SeparableConv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv2_1')(x)
x = SeparableConv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv2_2')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, name='pool2')(x)

x = SeparableConv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv3_1')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
x = SeparableConv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv3_2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn2')(x)

x = SeparableConv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', name='Conv3_3')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, name='pool3')(x)
x = Dropout(0.6, name='dropout0')(x)


x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.6, name='dropout1')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25, name='dropout2')(x)
x = Dense(14, activation='softmax', name='fc3')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x ,name='classification_pre_trained_encoder')
return model`
```

Comment: Did you shuffle the data before using it for validation?

Comment: How big is your test dataset size?

Comment: my training data is  72000*4048 ,where validation data was splitted 0.2 during fitting, and shuffle.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/sadiaeshakaggle/noise-6-peak-splitted-data

Comment: One possible reason I can think of is that the model performs poorly in classifying some of the 14 diseases and though you say you are shuffling, it is possible that many samples of this poorly performing class are grouped together in the validation split. See if you can get the classes distribution in your validation split.